# Install Windows, remove Ubuntu USB stick from Mac OSX

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mac, usb

I've got a problem.. I've installed Ubuntu on my PC (which's working fine by the way). But I want to install Windows XP on it again.

I have a Windows XP iso (which works fine in VirtualBox on my Mac) and I have created a "bootable" USB stick in the Mac Terminal with this:

**sudo dd if=Windows.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m**

However..

When I boot up my PC and press F11 for Boot menu, I choose "KingstoneDataTraveler.." 
But Ubuntu won't let me boot it! I only come to a "GNU GRUB version 2.00..." with the purple background. There I can choose between: Ubuntu, Advanced flags or memory test.

Any deas how to put Windows XP in this PC and remove Ubuntu? (Using Mac)

Comment: are you sure that /dev/disk2 is your USB drive?

Comment: Yes. I ran diskutil List... Only MacHD and my Usb stick (/dev1 and /dev2)

Comment: Raw copy of CDROM ISO file to a USB flash disk generally does not create a bootable disk. USB flash needs a different boot code and a different file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the GRUB menu, something is wrong with the USB drive, as you are not getting to the windows bootloader on it. Try following the instructions on creating a bootable USB on the Ubuntu website (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) substitutung the Ubunto ISO for your Windows one.

Also remember that you will need to ensure that windows does not need any additional drivers to read your USB stick (Kingston USBs do IIRC) otherwise you will not be able to complete the install

Comment: Hi! Actually I followed the instructions form Ubuntu. But I will consider testing another stick (I have a kingston stick as well)

Comment: The Ubuntu instructions contain a vital stem (ISO to IMG convertion) that you did not mention in your origanal post, which may be the issue.